# R: Extracting my response data from the formula I've inputted into a user-function

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function which does some analysis on the data.

Currently I have,

```
test = function(formula, data)
```

So when I want to use my function, I input something like:

```
test(response~predictor1+predictor+..., data = iris)
```

I can model a matrix of my predictors to use by doing:

```
mat = model.matrix(formula, data)
```

but this doesn't give me a column of response data. I can't figure out a way to access my response data so I can actually use it to do the calculations and generate the model. How can I use this formula to actually access my response data and use it?

Thanks,

EDIT: Example using the iris data from the ISLR package

Function:

```
test = function(formula, data){
mat = model.matrix(formula, data)
...(calculations and stuff - I don't need assistance with this part)
}
```

So to use my function:

```
model = test(Species~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data = iris)
```

Pretty much in my function up there, I can generate a matrix of the predictors to use (which I've called mat) and do calculations on but I don't know how to also generate a matrix/vector of the response data (Species).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited in some code for the iris data, not sure if this will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `model.response` and/or `model.frame`.

```
model.response(model.frame(Species~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data = iris))
##      1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
## setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa 
##      8          9         10         11         12         13         14 
## setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa 
##     15         16         17         18         19         20         21
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go but this looks exactly like what I want.